# Applying PUM Image 16 to Peoplesoft 9.2.00 FSCM

Tags: peoplesoft

We are currently on 9.2.00 FSCM and we want to move on to 9.2.16 i.e. we want to apply image 16 on existing application. Can someone help us out with the steps and procedure.

As Per our limited understanding, what we think is :

1. Download PI16 and set up a PUM environment.
2. Set existing environment as target.
3. Create a change package out of it .
4. Apply the change package to the existing environment.

Is above procedure correct ?
We raised an SR with the Oracle too, for the same reason. But, the response was too generic to take up.

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't watched it, but psadmin.io has some videos on it, and they have a pretty active slack channel where people ask and answer questions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will check out there too!